# merge two big csv files

Tags: csv

I have two the type of csv files,the first file's content is the following:

```
1 13733776062
2 13535581615
3 13987993374
4 13866603331
```

The second file's content is the following:

```
13535581615|1
13733776062|0
13866603331|0
13987993374|1
```

The first file's format of each line is:`id number`,the second file's format of each line is:`number flag`. They have a relationship field:`number`.

Each file has 10 million lines.
Now I want to combine the two files by the number field into a new file which contains 3 fields of `id,number,flag` of each line.I am using Java to do this.

Can someone tell me the best method for this work that consumes lower time?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: It's better to place some code here, what you already did to resolve problem...

Comment: I don't have any idea,the data is huge.

Comment: Try to write something just for couple of lines of data - maybe for your examples?

Comment: Can you elaborate or give me a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is task more appropriate for SQLite, not for Java. You can do it as follows:

```
$ sqlite3 database.db
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table1 (id int, number int);
sqlite> .separator " "
sqlite> .import t1.csv table1
sqlite> CREATE TABLE table2 (number int, flag int);
sqlite> .separator "|"
sqlite> .import t2.csv table2
sqlite> CREATE TABLE mytable AS
        SELECT t1.id, t1.number, t2.flag
        FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
        WHERE t1.number=t2.number;
sqlite> SELECT * FROM mytable;
1|13733776062|0
2|13535581615|1
3|13987993374|1
4|13866603331|0
```

I would expect that it should work for 10 million lines very fast.

And of course, you can use SQLite JDBC to create and access new database from Java.

To make access faster, it is good idea to create appropriate indexes.

Comment: The requirement is don't use database or embedded database.How can i do it?

Comment: All you need to have is [sqlite3 executable](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) and use my recipe. Then you can save output of last SELECT statement into a file, and you are done. If you don't like it, you will have to do it a hard way - i.e. you are on your own